# Find maximum of large (size) multiple rasters

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, digital-image-processing

I have several large rasters (300MB - 1GB), each raster has been reclassified with numpy array and GDAL blocks. I now need to create an output file with only the maximum value per pixel used in the output. If I just try to open each image as an array, I run out of memory. (in ESRI i would  use cell statistics set to MAX), but this needs to be accomplished with open source programming.

I am trying to open each file by block:

```
for i in range(0, rows, yBlocksize):
    if i + yBlocksize < rows:
        numRows = yBlocksize
    else:
        numRows = rows - i

        # loop through columns
    for j in range(0, cols, xBlocksize):
        if j + xBlocksize < cols:
            numCols = xBlocksize
        else:
            numCols = cols - j
        array1 = band1.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        print ("array1")
        print array1.shape

        array2 = band2.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        print ("array2")
        print array2.shape

        array3 = band3.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        print ("array3")
        print array3.shape

        array4 = band4.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        print ("array4")
        print array4.shape
```

From there, I have found several options for finding the 'max' however, I am getting stuck in the 'for' loop and my script will continuously print 'array1, array2' ect. If I add 'break' after array 4 it is ignored.

Other times I get a zero output, or errors:
"raise ValueError("expected array of dim 2") 
ValueError: expected array of dim 2"

I have to be missing something simple.
running:
python 2.7
GDAL 2.1.3
numpy 1.13.0

I have looked at the following links and tried pretty much all of these options:
[How to operate maximum value compose of some raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221692/how-to-operate-maximum-value-compose-of-some-raster-image)

[gdal/python WriteArray working for 8-bit but not 16-bit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184430/gdal-python-writearray-working-for-8-bit-but-not-16-bit)

[Optimising Min/Max temporal raster search in python/gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68560/optimising-min-max-temporal-raster-search-in-python-gdal)

[create a maximum raster using gdal_calc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221907/create-a-maximum-raster-using-gdal-calc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have also looked here - http://tretherington.blogspot.com/2015/04/some-stuff-import-numpy-as-npa-np.html

so it has to be the size of my raster data and/or reading the data into blocks.

Comment: Shouldn't the calculation for xMax and YMax be independent of each other?  two separate for loops, rather than nested

Comment: The way the 'for' loop is written is what I have learned through http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/ and have had great success in reclassifying the image with that format. the 'array' after that, I am not sure about.

Comment: You're right, @als.  I missed the use of the variable i inside the second for loop.

Comment: SOLVED: through a combination of already sited locations, and no function was needed. This solves with reading each array into blocks,

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: through a combination of already sited locations, and no function was needed. This solves with reading each array into blocks,

```
for i in   range(0, rows, yBlocksize):
    if i + yBlocksize < rows:
        numRows = yBlocksize
    else:
        numRows = rows - i

        for j in range(0, cols, xBlocksize):
            if j + xBlocksize < cols:
            numCols = xBlocksize
        else:
            numCols = cols - j

        array1 = band1.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        array2 = band2.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        array3 = band3.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)
        array4 = band4.ReadAsArray(j, i, numCols, numRows)

        z = np.dstack((array1, array2, array3, array4))
        print z.shape
        maxIndex = np.argmax(z, axis=2)
        nRow, nCol = np.shape(array1)
        col, row = np.meshgrid(range(nCol), range(nRow))

        maxValue = z[row, col, maxIndex]
        print maxValue

        outBand2a.WriteArray(maxValue, j, i)
```